# Jaxb marshalling - getting all fields in xml from java object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am using JAXB for marshalling java object to XML. I have generated the required java objects from xsd. I am able to marshall and get the xml as described below.

```
<Disk>
 <Details>
  <status>attached</status>
  <size>10000000000</size>
  <freeSpace>25600000<freeSpace>
  <id>MI45563PO</id>
 </Details>
</Disk>
```

But the xml contains only the fields, for which am setting the values and the mandatory fields (default values)in the schema. I need all the fields defined in the xsd(as empty) along with the fields, for which I have set values.

Java Code:

```
    Disk disk = new Disk();
    Details details = new Details();
    details.setSize(100000000);
    details .setDetails(details);

    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.samplefile");        

    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();

    marshaller.setProperty("jaxb.formatted.output",Boolean.TRUE);

    marshalle.marshal(details ,new FileOutputStream(new                           
     File("C:/test/Sample.xml")));
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the annotation

```
@XmlElement(nillable=true)
```

in all the fields of the class Details that can be null. 
For example

```
@XmlElement(nillable=true)
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
```

If that field contains a null value the output will be:

```
<status xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
```